# Get confirmation when href is available

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fetch the `href` of 10 dynamically loaded images.

I need to assign a variable name for the `href`.

My question is, how do I keep checking/confirm if `.splashIcon`'s is available before assigning the variable name and proceeding within the for loop?

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    if($('#elem' + i + ' .splashIcon')) {
    //how to make sure `('#elem' + i + ' .splashIcon')` is available?
         var one = $('#elem1 .splashIcon').attr( 'xlink:href');
         //do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: @DOWNvoter: Please care to comment as to why my question was down voted. That would help me next time.

Comment: This post is tagged with jquery, so can't you just put the code inside a $(document).ready() block to ensure the code only runs after the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 0):

first of all `selector` is wrong, it should `$('#elem' + i + '.splashIcon')` and it will be like `$('#elem1.splashIcon')`

answer:

you need to put condition `$('#elem' + i + '.splashIcon').length > 0` inside `if`

and you can get your `attr` value using `$('#elem' + i + '.splashIcon').attr( 'href');`